# Replace each special symbol with # in the following string

Tags: python, string, replace

```
import string 
str1 = '/*dave is @architect & telephone!!'
symbols = string.punctuation

for char in str1:
   if char in symbols:
      str2 = str1.replace(char, "#")
print(str2)
```

That's what I tried and the result is:

```
/*dave is @architect & telephone##
```

I don't understand why it is only changing the last 2 characters.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is.

After this line
`if char in symbols:` you change `str2` to `str1.replace(char,"#")` here `str1` is the original string, not the modified string.
So you need to use the below code. In You code you can try `print(str1)` before `str1.replace(char,"#")` this line to check if the `str1` is change or the same as original.

```py
import string 
str1 = '/*dave is @architect & telephone!!'
str2 = str1
symbols = string.punctuation

for char in str1:
    if char in symbols:
        str2 = str2.replace(char,"#")
print(str2)
```

You can also use list comprehension.

```py
import string 
str1 = '/*dave is @architect & telephone!!'
symbols = string.punctuation
str2 = ''.join(['#' if char in symbols else char for char in str1])
print(str2)
```